# How can I recover a file located in XCode's DerivedData folder, Index/DataStore/v5

Tags: xcode

I am trying to recover a lost file from Xcode 9, I have noticed that the data is available in the `/DerivedData/{project}/Index/DataStore/v5/records/{RA}/{filename.m-IA957FMXN1RA}`

When I open the file it is in binary format, I can see some of the code but it
is mingled with some binary characters.

Is it possible to `decode this file` in order to restore the source files?

Comment: It seems like some database `LMDB`. I have tried opening this DB using `FastoNoSQL` but have not succeeded with this.